# How to make Inno Setup installer keep temporary files either after installation completes or after VSTO installer completes?

Tags: installation, vsto, inno-setup, clickonce

I have Inno Setup installer (written before me) which extracts a set of VSTO files and starts VSTO MS Office addin installation then. It has a problem that upon extracting VSTO files into a temp folder and launching `VSTOInstaller.exe` it immediately displays *Finish* button. If the user clicks it, temporary files are deleted and starting the actual installation of VSTO addin in `VSTOInstaller` then results in "file not found" errors. I'm supposed to fix that (ideally, to have *Finish* button in Inno Setup installer appear only when `VSTOInstaller` spawned by it has finished execution).

VSTO package itself (a collection of "Application Files" folder, `setup.exe` and `.vsto` file) is created by ClickOnce Publish tool in Visual Studio. The package is digitally signed, etc.

I tried various options:

- To not finish the Inno Setup installation until the process which opens `.vsto` file finishes (with `waituntilterminated` flag). Doesn't work, seems the process changes during opening the `.vsto` file, `VSTOInstaller` isn't the first process in the chain. Thus, Inno Setup waits only for the process which quickly passes execution to another process (`VSTOInstaller`) and then shuts down.
- To not remove extracted files upon the installation (with `uninsneveruninstall` flag). Looks like it only works for uninstallation while removing temp files during the installation is somewhat different. I didn't find any way to keep the unpacked files intact after finishing the installation.

Currently `.iss` file looks like:

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
[Setup]
AppName=Outlook Addin
AppVerName=Outlook Addin 2.0
DefaultDirName={tmp}
DefaultGroupName=Outlook Sync Addin
Compression=bzip
Uninstallable=no
OutputBaseFilename=OutlookSetup
VersionInfoVersion=2.0.0.10
UsePreviousAppDir=no
;
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
[Files]
Source: "SourcesForExe\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Attribs: hidden system; Flags: recursesubdirs uninsneveruninstall
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\OutlookAddin.vsto"; Parameters: "OVERRIDE=YES"; StatusMsg: "Extracting Outlook Addin installer..."; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated
```

Originally, the installer run `setup.exe` rather than `OutlookAddin.vsto`. This caused `setup.exe` to launch `VSTOInstaller.exe` and immediately shut down. I thought changing to `OutlookAddin.vsto` (and adding `shellexec` flag) would fix that so that `VSTOInstaller.exe` would be launched directly by this method but but it didn't work. Turns out `.vsto` files are opened by `vstoee.dll` first.

Any idea how to either keep unpacked files (it's not a big deal that they will stay in temp folder) or somehow wait for all child processes spawned during the setup process?

If that matters, Inno Setup is 5.2.3, VSTO is built with Visual Studio 2015. Tested with Outlook 2010 and 2016.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`{tmp}`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts&anchor=tmp) is setup's temporary folder, which gets deleted at the end. If you want to preserve the files, explicitly refer to the user's temporary folder using `TEMP` environment variable:

```
DefaultDirName={%TEMP}\outlook_addin_tmp
```

---

Though, it is a hack – the correct solution would be to wait for the VSTO installer to finish. I suggest you start the `VSTOInstaller.exe` explicitly. It should allow you to wait for it to complete

Something like this:

```
Filename: "{commonpf}\microsoft shared\VSTO\<ver>\VSTOInstaller.exe"; \
  Params: "{app}\OutlookAddin.vsto"; \
  StatusMsg: "Extracting Outlook Addin installer..."; Flags: waituntilterminated
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently created this same as u required.
It is working fine for me, Start setup.exe then searches for VSTO process and binds exit event to it.

```
            var process = Process.Start("Setup.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            var processs = Process.GetProcesses().Where(i => i.ProcessName.Contains("VSTO")).ToList();
            foreach (var item in processs)
            {
                if (item.ProcessName.Contains("VSTO"))
                {                   
                    item.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                    item.Exited += ExcelProcessExit; // this method will be executed after vsto completes it's installation or user cancels the installer.
                }
            }
```